# Besides the (currently down) HDEV, are there other public live video feeds from the ISS?

Tags: iss, communication, telemetry, video, hdev

I am working on spacecraft simulation software, and I would like to validate my ISS simulation that uses [ISS-Mimic](https://github.com/ISS-Mimic/Mimic)'s code to connect to live ISS telemetry. I already have some early validation done with sites like [ISS Tracker 3D](http://www.satflare.com/track.asp), but I want to validate my visual models of the ISS and earth with real, live video.

I have already found one stream that appears to be live: http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream, but the video hasn't changed from blue-screen for the past ~10 minutes. We do have live audio; I'm now hearing Jessica Meir get tech support from the ground.

[HDEV](https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/), which has been down for a few months, would have been a perfect solution. I am pretty sure there are other video streams that are active for ISS operations, but are any of those publicly available?

Comment: good to know about ISS-Mimic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it appears they are now using the EHDC, a different camera that doesn't always have availability, to provide a live video feed. It would be great to get access to additional feeds though.

https://eol.jsc.nasa.gov/ESRS/HDEV/

Answer (score -2):

The live_ISS feed and the EHDC feed are all there is. The blue screen happens due to LOS (loss of signal) over the Stan countries until it is close to OZ, where the next TDRS (US-operated Data Relay Satellite) picks up the signal and transmits it to White Sands New Mexico and then to JSC. There are many other feeds of the ISS signal but they are all using the same one you will find on IBM/ustream.

Comment: Welcome to Space Exploration Stack Exchange! To improve your answers in the future, please cite sources and spend some more time editing the capitalization and punctuation of your post (I made some edits for you just now).

Comment: TDRSS has coverage over Eastern Europe. There is no ISS TDRS LOS there. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/13297/6944