# Which type of map projection is most commonly used in control rooms?

Tags: tracking, mission-control

Mission control rooms often have a large map of the Earth (or other body being orbited) with a track of the orbit of the spacecraft.  **What type of [map projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) is commonly used for these displays?**

Comment: some images [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40273) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19402) and [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37021)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection). Note that in all of the images that uhoh linked ([a](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40273) [b](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19402) [c](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37021)), the grid squares on the map are the same size and shape at all points on the map.

Here's an example from [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13296/29766) question, apparently showing a screen from the ISS MCC:

[image: Main Screen in the ISS Mission Control Center]

also showing how all the grid elements are the same shape in all places on the map, though they're not squares here.